# Assembly code: Add and xor logic

Tags: assembly

I'm looking at a puzzle in a textbook and I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the assembly instructions correctly. The way I have understood it, it's telling me to find two numbers that sum to 6005 and xor to give 0.

Doesn't this mean that the numbers are equal to each other? But how can they be, given that their sum is 6005? Is it possible to find a pair of such numbers, or have I interpreted the assembly code incorrectly? Let me know what you think! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statements are contradictory :

Let's assume that they xor to 0 and their sum is 6005; That means both number are equal;

Both numbers are either pair or impair

Assuming pair: 2k + 2k = 4k = 2(2K) = 2k = A pair number

Assuming impair 2k + 1 + 2k + 1 = 4k + 2 = 2 (2k + 1) = 2k = A pair number

6005 = 2 (3002) + 1 = 2k + 1 = Impair number.

So it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code of the puzzle and the specific CPU the code is targeted. For example for x86:

```
mov   eax, 3002
stc
adc   eax, eax   ; the result is 6005

xor   eax, eax   ; the result zero
```

Comment: "two numbers that sum to 6005" usually means `a + b = 6005`, not `a + b + 1 = 6005`. Together with `xor (a,b) = 0` means that there is no such pair of numbers.

Comment: Yes, of course, but we don't know the actual conditions of the puzzle. I am just guessing. Maybe this textbook problem is about the carry flags.